# How do I accommodate for change of "targets" in a GOAP AI model?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-development

Say the agent is looking to perform a series of actions requiring different "targets" (picking up an item, eating a food, etc.). The way we chose to implement this is for each agent to store its current target as a field which can then be represented as key-value state (along with the other state) to be fed to the GOAP planner.

The problem arises if a series of actions requires the agent to let's say first eat a mushroom `m` and then go pick up a sword `s`. Ideally, the planner might find an action path similar to this:

locate m -> go to m -> pick up m -> eat m -> locate s -> go to s -> pick up s

Of course, we would like to generalize our actions as much as possible, so our current design has actions like goTo, pickUp, eat, etc. generalized to simply trust the preceding "locate x" action to have located a valid target.

In other words, locate x will have a promise state of `target == x` whereas an action like goTo will have the required state of `hasTarget == true` and a promise state of `isNearTarget == true`. A similar "generalized" set of requirements and goals are present for pickUp. The eat action will then have a requirement akin to `holdingTarget == true` and `target == Food`, while also setting target to null after the food has been consumed.

The big problem then is that what happens when m is eaten? How can the planner know that the next thing to locate is a sword and not something else? How can this be represented in GOAP-states in a way that ensures that the following actions will behave as expected?

One idea that came up was to divide actions into 3 categories:

- Designating - Actions that promise to set the target to a thing (i.e. locateFood)
- Intermediary - Actions that make generalized target promises (i.e. goTo)
- Terminal - Actions that "consume" the target, nulling it (i.e. eat)

This approach then comes with the question of knowing what actions are terminal and which aren't, which seems like a nasty problem on its own.

I'm sorry if this is too abstracted and hard to understand - I'm trying to generalize the problem away from our specific code since I don't think it's something specific to our implementation, but likely a misunderstanding on our part of how state is supposed to be represented in GOAP. I can provide code as well as any clarification if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be good if you showed some code.
Second, I'm hoping you've already looked at this [goap demo](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/goal-oriented-action-planning-for-a-smarter-ai--cms-20793)

This should answer your question.  Preconditions are to be met before an action is presented.  So for example, if you require the AI to eat the muchroom m before picking up a sword, I would do something like this:

Eat mushroom action:
effect: "mushroomEaten" == true

Pick up sword action:
precondition: if "mushroomEaten" == true

then

effect: "goPickUpSword"

I have to generalize since your question is also general with no specific code example given.  Look at the link provided and you will understand how actions can be chained together to accomplish a goal.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to reply, holidays and all!


While what you propose is a solution, it doesn't seem very feasible to me in the long run. Does this mean there needs to be an EatSteakAction and an EatPastaAction each with their own PickupSteakAction, FindNearestSteakAction, etc? Surely there is a way to generalize this beyond that?

Comment: You might get away with only an EatSteakAction. Within the respective action's checkProceduralPrecondition method, that's where you will do your distance calculation for the nearest steak or place where the character will go to eat it(like a table or park bench ).  Here's a quick gist I made to help clarify [link](https://gist.github.com/lionboy1/31a3c8087271900a1139bb8a70df921e).  The EatSteakAction selects the nearest steak, the NPC goes to it, then eats. Same idea for the pickupSteakAction if needed.  Just either search via tag or loop through an array of Game Objects to perform an action.